# Logic Pro X 10.1 update button does nothing

Tags: macos, mac-appstore, software-update, logic

I have Logic 10.0.7 and got a notice to update to 10.1. I press on the Update Now button but nothing happens. I have OS X 10.9.5 installed. What should I do?

Answer (score 2):

Try resetting the Mac App Store.

1. Enable the debug menu and restart the Mac App Store.

   ```
   defaults write com.apple.appstore ShowDebugMenu -bool true
   ```
2. Choose the **Reset Application** option.

   [image: App Store Debug Menu]